# Validate embed form if not empty

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entities: `Program` and `Widget`

**Program**

```
class Program
{
     ....
    /**
     * @Assert\Valid
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Widget", inversedBy="program", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $widget;
}
```

**Widget**

```
class Widget
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $addressId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $extAddressId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Program", mappedBy="widget")
     */
    private $program;
}
```

I have two issues.

First I need to add a conditional constraint on `Widget`, `addressId` or `extAddressId` have te be defined, not both.

Second `widget` is not required for `Program`. It's either you let all form fields blank, like you don't want to add a widget to the form OR you fill the form but you have to respect the conditional constraint and of course the required fields.

I was trying to add a `Callback` as it's explained in the official doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/reference/constraints/Callback.html) but I have no idea how to combine both.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define Assert von widget relation, like

```
Column Widet
@Assert\Valid()
```

As next, you have to work with expressions on the widget itself, like

```
Column adressId
@Assert\Expression(
     *     expression=" (this.getAdressId() and !this.extAdressId()) or !this.getAdressId() ",
     *     message="error.cant_be_enabled_with_adress_id"
     * )

Column extAdressId
@Assert\Expression(
     *     expression=" (this.getExtAddressId() and !this.getAdressId()) or !this.getExtAdressId() ",
     *     message="error.cant_be_enabled_with_adress_id"
     * )
```